# Troubling Recursive Fractal Mountain

Tags: c++, opengl, recursion, fractals

I am writing some OpenGl code to create a fractal mountain. I am using recursion, and am having a tough time.

The problem I am having is with the tearing and overlapping of the triangles: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha7gx.jpg

The problem is, I thought I had solved the issue, here is my code.

My Triangle class, vec2 is just a generic 2 dimensional vector

```
struct Triangle {
vec2 A, B, C;

Triangle(vec2 a, vec2 b, vec2 c) {
    A = a;
    B = b;
    C = c;
};
```

Here is my recursive function, which is originally called with a triangles of vertices (-1, -1), (0, 1), and (1, -1) in the default viewing volume.

```
 void divide_triangle(const Triangle& baseTriangle, int count) {

if (count > 0) {
    std::vector<Triangle> subTriangles = subdivideTriangle(baseTriangle);
    for (int i = 0; i < subTriangles.size(); i++) {
        divide_triangle(subTriangles[i], count - 1);
    }
}

else {
    triangle(baseTriangle); // Draw triangle at the end of recursion
}
```

This is my subDivideTriangles function which simply divides the passed triangle into four separate triangles

```
std::vector<Triangle> subdivideTriangle(const Triangle& triangle){

vec4 aPrime = getMidpoint(triangle.B, triangle.C);
vec4 bPrime = getMidpoint(triangle.C, triangle.A);
vec4 cPrime = getMidpoint(triangle.A, triangle.B);

return{
    { Triangle(triangle.A, cPrime, bPrime) }, // Top triangle
    { Triangle(cPrime, triangle.B, aPrime) }, // Bottom left triangle
    { Triangle(bPrime, aPrime, triangle.C) }, // Bottom right triangle
    { Triangle(cPrime, aPrime, bPrime) }      // Center triangle
};
```

And here is the function which I thought would stop the tearing, I keep track of the midpoint values corresponding to a pair of vectors, and if I find the corresponding vector pair, I return the original midpoint, therefore not moving the midpoint twice.

However, this method does not seem to work as I thought.

```
vec4 getMidpoint(const vec4& a, const vec4& b) {

auto AB = std::make_pair(a, b), BA = std::make_pair(b, a);

auto foundResult1 = memo.find(AB);
auto foundResult2 = memo.find(BA);

if (foundResult1 != memo.end())
    return memo[AB];

if (foundResult2 != memo.end())
    return memo[BA];

auto result = (a + b) / 2; 
result += randVector() * getLength(a, b) * randomness; 

memo.insert(std::make_pair(AB, result)); 
memo.insert(std::make_pair(BA, result));

return result;
```

Do you guys have any insight, is something wrong in my midpoint function?

Comment: Are you trying to make a Sierpinski triangle?  If so you should know that it is created from a equilateral triangle and your points do not make an equilateral triangle.

Comment: No, I am trying to make a fractal mountain like this: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-swU-5zFA8i8/U-puHDj8gyI/AAAAAAAAANU/W2gSvLFK8EM/s1600/mountain_python.bmp    Also, how is my triangle not equilateral? The (0, 0) point is in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is from adjacent edges.

Say you have two triangles ABC and DBC, with BC as common edge, and you want to modify them by adding some noisy middle point.

You use two different point for the middle of BC depending on the triangle.

- Let E be the middle of BC when you work on ABC to modify it.
- Let F be the middle of BC when you work on DBC to modify it.

E and F have to be the same. Otherwise big gap appears. It is easily visible on your picture.

In my opinion, you should work with indexed vertex and have a table (or any method) to find already existing middle of a given edge. ie: when it come to compute F middle of BC in DBC we check and find that it already exist as E.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Although I thought I had already did this with my `getMidpoint(const vec4& a, const vec4& b)` function, which makes a pair of the two endpoints, and then searches a map for the corresponding pair. If the pair is not found, it creates a new noisy midpoint, if the pair is found, it returns the already computer midpoint.

Comment: Here is my map:                                                                               `std::map<std::pair<vec4, vec4>, vec4> memo;`

Comment: My c++ is dusty, for me your approach is the good one. You should test that you code retrieve correctly an existing point. In your code you test for existence (find) then retrieve the element (use of []) which is suboptimal (two run trough the map). And I'm not sure your keys will be consistent (two pair<v4, v4> object with the same coordinate : are there really going to match the same element ?). Once again using index should be considered, it will also provide better memory perf in the opengl library.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! Yeah, I realized that the vectors are going to change, so I thought I would use the memory location associated with the vector object, because it will be unique. However, it still refuses to fix the tearing.